# Is $\mathbb{P}((a,b)) = \tan^{-1}(b) - \tan^{-1}(a)$ a valid probability measure on $X = (0, \infty)$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, borel-measures

Is $\mathbb{P}((a,b)) = \tan^{-1}(b) - \tan^{-1}(a)$ a valid probability measure on $X = (0, \infty)$ ?

I recently came across this question and thought that this is not a valid probability measure as the this will map the entire sample space interval to $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

It is given that $\mathbb{P}$ is a function that maps $\sigma$ algebra to the $\mathbb{R}^+$. So I thought that we can form a Borel algebra on $X = (0, \infty)$, then try to prove the given function is indeed a probability measure or not.

While the above function satisfies the $1^{st}$ axiom of probability measure, for the 2nd axiom:
$\mathbb{P}((0,\infty)) = \tan^{-1}(\infty) - \tan^{-1}(0) = \frac{\pi}{2} \neq 1 $. Hence, I thought $\mathbb{P}$ is not a valid probability measure. Also, the range of $\mathbb{P}$ is outside $[0,1]$. But, it was said to be a valid probability measure without giving any reason in the solution.

Is this function a valid probability measure, if so how does this satisfy the $2^{nd}$ axiom?

Comment: Finite measures can be made probability measures by normalizing by the measure of the whole space. Sometimes, authors can be a little lax and not make this clear.

Comment: Oh, does that mean that the measure given above is not a probability measure by itself but modifying it to $\mathbb{P}((a,b)) = \frac{\tan^{-1}(b) - \tan^{-1}(a)}{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ will be?

Comment: Yes @CraigWilder

Comment: You can check out Cauchy distribution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution
It's quite similar to your case

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.